# get a data from one table and with that data get all the data from other tables

Tags: python, sql

i have 2 tables .
in one table i have the details about the product ,for example:book
it contains International Standard Book Number. it is the foreign key.
in another table, i have the details about the ordered book. for example: user id for the user who ordered the book and isbn number.
i want to show the user what the ordered product.
so i need to get the isbn number from order table and from that isbn number get the data from the book table.

this is for python flask.
i don't know how to get the data from another table when the userid is not common in both the tables

```
@app.route('/myorder',methods=['GET','POST'])
def myorder():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cur=connection.cursor()
        user_id=session['userid']
        cur.execute("SELECT ISBN FROM orders WHERE user_id=%s",[user_id])
        data=cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
    return render_template('myorder.html',data=data)
```

i expect a single query for getting the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select book details from a join query I guess :

```
select books.* from books join orders on books.isbn = orders.isbn 
where orders.user_id = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

So what u have is a table with Book detail and ISBN no and Another Table with the User and ISBN no. So the simplest way to get the details of the book would be this:

```
    cur.execute("select booktable.bookdetails from booktable A, UserTable B
    where A.ISBNno = B.ISBNno
    and B.userID = %s", [user_id])
```

or if you want all the columns

```
    cur.execute("select booktable.* from booktable A, UserTable B
    where A.ISBNno = B.ISBNno
    and B.userID = %s", [user_id])
```

Comment: book details contains several columns, for example i have title , author,publisher,date of publishing,description, available copies,price. i have to display the details of the whole table

Comment: updated the code to add all the columns, u can list each  columns you want like this too: `booktable.column1, booktable.column2,.....`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the same
    `select books.* from books where isbn in (select isbn from orders where user_id = ?)`...